# Problems obtaining objective coefficient range

Tags: r, optimization

The constraints and objective function are listed below in the following pictures. I used the code

```
get.sensitivity.obj(lp_model)
```

but obtained weird results like:

```
$objfrom
[1] -1.000000e+30  4.384615e+01  5.020000e+01  2.220000e+01
[5]  2.220000e+01

$objtill
[1] 4.360000e+01 5.029412e+01 5.720000e+01 1.000000e+30
[5] 1.000000e+30
```

I wonder where are the possible errors?

[image]

[image]

I did try to check the tableu below, but I don't think it is wrong:

```
library(lpSolve)
library(lpSolveAPI)

lp_model <- make.lp(nrow = 0, ncol = 5) #make empty tableau shell

set.objfn(lprec=lp_model, obj = c(30,44,57,55,45)) #objective function:profit

lp.control(lprec = lp_model, sense = "max")

#add constraints
add.constraint(lprec = lp_model, xt = c(1,1,1.3,0.5,0.5),type = '<=',rhs = 40) #Frame constraints
add.constraint(lprec = lp_model, xt = c(1,1.2,1.5,2,1.5),type = '<=',rhs = 80) #Stretching constraints
add.constraint(lprec = lp_model, xt = c(1,1.5,1.7,1,1),type = '<=',rhs = 60) #Finishing constraints
add.constraint(lprec = lp_model, xt = c(0,0,0,1,0),type = '<=',rhs = 10) #Coffee table constraints
add.constraint(lprec = lp_model, xt = c(0,0,0,0,1),type = '<=',rhs = 10) #End table constraints

solve(lp_model)

get.variables(lp_model)
get.objective(lp_model)
get.sensitivity.obj(lp_model)
get.sensitivity.rhs(lp_model)
```

Comment: your variables need to be non-negative integers. You can achieve that in `lpSolve` with `all_int = TRUE`

Comment: I added the following: add.constraint(lprec = lp_model, xt = c(1,0,0,0,0),type = '>=',rhs = 0) 
add.constraint(lprec = lp_model, xt = c(0,1,0,0,0),type = '>=',rhs = 0) 
add.constraint(lprec = lp_model, xt = c(0,0,1,0,0),type = '>=',rhs = 0)
add.constraint(lprec = lp_model, xt = c(0,0,0,1,0),type = '>=',rhs = 0) 
add.constraint(lprec = lp_model, xt = c(0,0,0,0,1),type = '>=',rhs = 0)

Comment: but the result is still weird numbers